# Derivative of a Polynomial via HashMap. How to iterate over HashMap<Degree,Coeff>?

Tags: java, performance, time, iterator, hashmap

I would like to write a derivate method for a polynomials. My input format is a HashMap storing degree and coefficient. this way (comparing to Array type input) is better in terms of space if your polynomials have lots of zero coefficient, yet according to my code I need to iterate n times where n is degree of polynomial, not a size of HashSet. Like 1+x^100 has HashMap size 2, yet degree is 100. To reduce time complexity, I need to do calculation only over HashSet. Can we reduce number of iteration from n to HashMap size? Here is my code:

```
public static HashMap<Integer, Double> derivativePoly2(HashMap<Integer, Double> degreeAndCoeff) {
    int len = degreeAndCoeff.size();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < Integer.MAX_VALUE && len - 1 > 0) {
        if (degreeAndCoeff.containsKey(i + 1)) {
            --len;
            degreeAndCoeff.put(i, degreeAndCoeff.get(i + 1) * (i + 1));
            degreeAndCoeff.remove(i + 1);
        }
        ++i;
    }

    return degreeAndCoeff;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the iterator of your entry set or key set.  For example:

```
public static Map<Integer, Double> derivativePoly2(Map<Integer, Double> degreeAndCoeff) {
    Map<Integer, Double> result = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> term : degreeAndCoeff.entrySet() {
        int exponent = term.getKey();
        double coefficient = term.getValue();

        // ... result.put(something, somethingElse);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: When I wrote this :deggreeAndCoeff.put(entry.getKey()-1, entry.getValue()*entry.getKey()); it gave an error. I would like to do in place-using same HashMap. But when I create the new one, it does work. What is wrong with  deggreeAndCoeff.put(entry.getKey()-1, entry.getValue()*entry.getKey())? Thank you!

Comment: You cannot modify the map while an iteration over one of its collection views is in progress, else the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.  If you wish, after you finish computing the derivative, you can do `degreeAndCoeff.clear(); degreeAndCoeff.putAll(result);` to return the result in the original `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` would not provide you with ordering of keys (which I believe is what hyou need in this case).

[TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is a class which will have key ordering. You could then iterate through it like that:

```
for(Map.Entryp<Integer, Double> entry : degreeAndCoeff.entrySet()) {
  Integer key = entry.getKey();
  Double value = entry.getValue();
}
```

**EDIT**: As John Bollinger suggested in the comments, ordering of the keys doesn't matter when calculating derivative, therefore you could simpley iterate over a `HashMap`, exactly the same way as I demonstrated above with the `TreeMap`.

Comment: It is correct that `HashMap`s are not iterated in an order that is easily predictable from their keys.  Generally speaking, however, the terms of a polynomial can be processed in any order in the computation of its derivative.